# Is there a PyTorch counterpart of Tensorflow Keras methods get_weights and set_weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

Are there any counterparts of TF/Keras methods `get_weights()` and `set_weights()` in the PyTorch framework for obtaining quickly model's weights and setting new ones?
Or maybe there are other easy methods to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`set_weights` [TENSORFLOW](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#set_weights)

#### [How to change the weights of a pytorch model?](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-change-the-weights-of-a-pytorch-model/41279/2)

Would you like to change the weights manually?

If so, you could wrap the code in a torch.no_grad() guard:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    model.fc.weight[0, 0] = 1.
```

to prevent Autograd from tracking these changes.

#### [How to manually set the weights in a two layer linear model?](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-manually-set-the-weights-in-a-two-layer-linear-model/45902/2)

You would just need to wrap it in a `torch.no_grad()` block and manipulate the parameters as you want:

```
model = torch.nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(10, 1, bias=False))

with torch.no_grad():
    model[0].weight = nn.Parameter(torch.ones_like(model[0].weight))
    model[0].weight[0, 0] = 2.
    model[0].weight.fill_(3.)
```